# Endless scrolling for Three20's TTScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, scroll, three20

In my application I'm using the TTScrollView class to create a sliding menu.  I was wondering if it was possible to make it so when you try to scroll to the next item and you're at the last one you loop back to the first item again?  Preferably it would work from going to the first item to the last one as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check InfinitePagingView. It provides horizontal and vertical infinite scrolling.
https://github.com/caesarcat/InfinitePagingView